# Placement of parameters in code: methods vs properties

Tags: excel, vba

I'm just trying to get the rules straight in my head...

For instance, using a METHOD (Add) I can do this:

```
Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(1)
```

... but the following use of a Property (Resize) throws an error:

```
Selection.Resize.Select ColumnSize:=4
```

It's not a big deal given that this:

```
Selection.Resize(ColumnSize:=4).Select
```

... or several other ways of doing it works, but I'm just trying to get my head around if there is an official rule that states you can do the post-placement of a parameter (say that quick!) with a Method but you can't with a Property.

(I'm also kind of confused as to why Resize is a Property rather than a Method, so if anyone knows the answer to that that would be a bonus, but I suppose it isn't that important).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `Selection.Resize.Select ColumnSize:=4` this is illogical because the `resize` property does not have any members called `Select` and `Select` (if it were to exist) does not accept a parameter called `ColumnSize`.

Why `Selection.Resize(ColumnSize:=4).Select` works is because you have essentially written

```
Dim TempRange as Range
set TempRange = Selection.Resize(ColumnSize:=4)
TempRange.Select
Set TempRange = Nothing
```

But it is all on one line.

Related to this is an [awesome article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx?Redirected=true) written by Eric Lippert about VBA parantheses gotcha's

Comment: Thanks Brad - makes great sense.

Comment: Nice explanation. Tangentially, and perhaps interestingly, the `ListObject` has a `Resize` method which takes a `Range` argument :).

Comment: Reviving an old post just to make a correction in case anyone stumbles across this in a search: AFAIK this line is incorrect: `set TempRange = Selection.Resize ColumnSize:=4`. Because `Resize` is a Property and not a Method, it requires its arguments to have parentheses around them. `Set TempRange = Selection.Resize(ColumnSize:=4)` is the correct form.

Comment: Right you are @EndlessLoop. feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: @EndlessLoop well I see your edit was rejected...I just made the edit myself. sigh

Comment: All good. It didn't let me do less than a 6 character edit -- so maybe the explanation I added to make it more than that wasn't considered useful.